# Symfony2 - Authentication login..... service

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.1

I had this application (running already on prod) for a while. The thing is that as a new project for this application I need to add a couple of rest services for authenticated users.
Currently the security is handled by Sf2 (doctrine2 user provider). Pretty standard stuff.

So i been thinking about creating a new entity with a Token field (randomly created) and User.
(since this sessions needed to persist).
And then on my new controller who will provide the rest responses (json) add this token as a param, adding also one that will take user/password and return a new token.

That's my idea, but maybe there is a better way of doing so, more standard or some kind of provider. Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement your webservice with the [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) under a dedicated route (ex /api) and secure it with [FOSOAuthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle).